# How to not re-render React component's specific DOM elements?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sigma.js

Recently I started to refactor my *Backbone* web app with *React* and I'm trying to write interactive graph visualization component using *react* and *sigma.js*.

I roughly understood *React*'s declarative paradigm and how it is implemented by `render()` method using *jsx* syntax.

**But what gets me stumbled is a situation where I cannot define my *React* component declarativly.**

It is because of the javascript-generated DOM elements, which only can be generated on `componentDidMount()` after the declarative DOM elements are rendered by `render()`.

It makes me worried about both performance and buggy animations (my graph animates on instantiation time, which will be re-played on every `render()` calls in this situation)

My current code looks like:

```
...

render: function() {
  return (
    <div class="my-graph-visualization-component">
      {/*
          This div is defined declaratively, so won't be re-rendered
          on every `change` events* unless `React`'s diff algorithm 
          think it needs to be re-rendered.
      */}
      <div class="my-declarative-div">{this.props.text}</div>

      {/*
          This div will be filled by javascript after the `render()`
          call. So it will be always cleared and re-rendered on every
          `change` events.
      */}
      <div class="graph-container MY-PROBLEM-DIV"></div>
    </div>
  );
},

componentDidMount: function() {
  this.props.sigmaInstance.render('.graph-container', this.props.graph);
}

...
```

Is there any way to do something like

```
render: function() {
  return (
    <div class="my-graph-visualization-component">
      <div class="my-declarative-div">{this.props.text}</div>

      {/* 
          Any nice workaround to tell react not to re-render specific
          DOM elements? 
      */}
      <div class="graph-container NO-RE-RENDER"></div>
    </div>
  );
},
```

so that my *sigma.js* graph component won't get re-instantiated with identical starting animation on every `change` on states?

Since it seems to be it is about **handling non-declarative part of react components**, any workarounds for this kind of problem will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm interested by the same problems, have you found something?

Comment: You could use [react-sigma](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-sigma), which does re-rendering only when sigma properties or graph changed. See sources https://github.com/dunnock/react-sigma/tree/master/src

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cleanest way is to define  react sub-components and re-render what you really need instead of re-rendering the whole block

```
render: function() {

    return (
       <div class='myStaticContainerNotupdated'>
           <SubComponentToUpdateOften/>
           <MyGraph/>
       </div>
    )

}
```

The other solution could be to work on your graph and implement a singleton so your animation is only played once at the first render.

But really the easiest and cleanest thing I see is to create clean separate subcomponent and update them when needed. You never update the big container component just the subs one.

Hope it helps

Comment: One more question... Then how should I implement `<MyGraph />` component in *React*ive manner? `<MyGraph />` will have it's graph object as it's state and should  update it's display via `refresh()` method  (this method will be provided by library), not `render()` of *React*, on it's graph state changes.. **What I really don't know is how to implement these javascript-defined (defined by code, not jsx) components.**

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. <MyGraph/> is a react component on its own. Its own state and render function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html). This basically tells React to stay away from it’s content and it wont evaluate/update it when doing it’s DOM diffing.